# Setting up OpenVPN to connect to VPN with 2FA (google Auth)

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have an issue with my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, where I am required to login to the office VPN using OpenVPN.

The system administrator gave us the connect.ovpn file which works without issues when using CLI to connect. It asks for my username, password and the response code from Authenticator (so basically same as the GUI on Win).

However, I am not able to set-up the connection using NM (importing the settings from the .ovpn file) as it never asks for the Authenticator Response, just  the "Password".

I've tried various suggestions from this forum and others (moving files to /etc/Network Manager, reinstalling the whole OpenVPN package, selecting manually the key/certificate), but none seems to work.

I found and older thread (Ubuntu 16.04) which states that it is not possible to connect to a 2FA VPN using GUI/NM at this moment, thus I am trying to find out if it still the issue and if I should give up.

If you need any information, please let me know and I'll check if I am allowed to post it.

Thank you.